# Tangent space of $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ at a point $l$.

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

Consider the manifold $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$. Let $l \in \mathbb{CP}^{2}$ be arbitrary. Define $F: \mathbb{C}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{3}$ to be the reflection in the line $l \subset \mathbb{C}^{3}$.

I have now found the following claim:

> The tangent space $T_{l}\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ can be identified with the  space of Hermitian operators $A$ on $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ such that $AF + FA = 0$.

It is unclear to me how this identification would go. Let's choose a unit vector $z \in l$. My guess would be that we may identify a smooth function $f: \mathbb{CP}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with a unique smooth function $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{C}^{3}\setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we could then define the derivation
\begin{equation}
 A \triangleright f = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\bigg|_{t=0}  \tilde{f}\left(z + t A z \right).
\end{equation}

> **Question:** Is this correct? If no, how does the identification work? If yes, how to show this...